# Selecting one mesh island from group based on attributes in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hello Blender community!

I've been working on a pattern using Geometry Nodes in Blender and have encountered a challenge. I want to delete two out of three mesh islands within each "group," where a group is defined by having a common attribute called "group" with the same numeric value unique for each group (indicated by the blue color in the image below). To achieve this, I have already created two attributes using Geometry Nodes. The first attribute provides an individual index for each element (shown in orange) based on mesh island node, and the second attribute assigns the same number to every three elements forming a group (shown in blue).

Here's a visual representation of part of the pattern I've created using Geometry Nodes:

[image]

Initially, I attempted to randomly delete every third mesh island, but this approach proved too random and sometimes deleted all three elements from a group, which is not what I intended.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My example .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modulo each island index 0 to 2 and randomly offset it
[image]